# SSE "data" field not being received by Dart http.client

Tags: flutter, http, dart, mobile, server-sent-events

I'm building a Flutter app that receives SSE from a server and translates them to specific notifications. The server is a Spring Boot app returning events containing **"event:"** and **"data:"** fields:

```
public void pushNotification(String username, PushEvent event) {
    var emitter = emitters.get(username);
    if (emitter == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        emitter.send(event.toSseEvent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.debug("Could not send event for user " + username);
        emitters.remove(username);
    }
}

public class PushEvent {
    private String type;
    private Map<String, Object> body;

    public SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder toSseEvent() {
        return SseEmitter.event().name(type).data(body);
    }
}
```

On the Flutter app, I use the Dart [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to open a Stream and receive the events:

```
Future<void> subscribe() async {
if (!_userModel.hasAuthentication()) {
  return;
}

var user = _userModel.user as AuthenticatedUser;
var username = user.username;
var token = _userModel.getToken();

var uri = Uri.https(ApiUtils.API_BASE, '/api/push/subscribe/$username');
try {
  var client = http.Client();
  _client = client;

  var request = new http.Request("GET", uri);
  request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";
  request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
  request.headers["Authorization"] = token;

  var response = await client.send(request);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    _isSubscribed = true;
    response.stream.toStringStream().forEach((value) {
      var event = ServerEvent.parse(value);
      _handleEvents(event);
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      log.info("Connection closed");
      log.info(error);
      log.info(stackTrace);
      unsubscribe();
    }).whenComplete(() {
      log.info("Connection completed");
      unsubscribe();
      subscribe();
    });
  } else {
    _isSubscribed = false;
  }
  notifyListeners();
} catch (e) {
  unsubscribe();
  log.warning("Could not subscribe to notifications");
  log.warning(e);
}
```

}

However, when I receive an event containing data from the server, the data does not show on the log:

```
I/flutter (14779): event:FRIEND_REQUEST
I/flutter (14779): data:
```

I am certain the data is being sent by the server since the React app on the same domain decodes the SSE and shows the notifications as intended:

```
const subscribePush = () => {
  const username = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUsername');
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  var es = new EventSourcePolyfill(
    '/api/push/subscribe/' + username,
    {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": token,
      }
    }
    );
  
  es.onerror = () => es.close();
  es.addEventListener("FRIEND_REQUEST", e => handleFriendRequestEvent(e));
  es.addEventListener("FRIEND_ACCEPT", e => handleFriendAcceptEvent(e));
}

const handleFriendRequestEvent = function (event) {
  const username = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedUsername");
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  const source = data.source;
  if (source !== username) {
    var note  = `${source} solicitou sua amizade!`;
    var newNotifs = notifications.concat(note);
    setNotifications(newNotifs);
    setNewNotifications(newNotifications + 1);
  }
}
```

Could something be missing from the request on the Flutter app, or is it possibly a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks strangely similar to this one:

```
https://github.com/stevenroose/dart-eventsource
```

Take a look at the client implementation and how the response in decoded using the `decoder.dart` file.